# How to deploy machine learning models containing only python functions

Tags: python, deployment

I am required to deploy my machine learning models in any environment for the purpose of demonstration to the Management. My models consist of only functions and not classes i.e.

```
a.py
def function1
def function2

b.py
def function3
def function4


Function_Calls.py
z = b.function4 (data processing)
u = b.function3 (test train data)
a.function1(z) (Model calling)
a.function2(u) (Model predictions)
```

How do I deploy my models in such scenario?

Expected: My model should take input data/ test data from a file and then based on the models, make predictions.

Comment: You can `import a, b` and do exactly what you expect, did you try?

Comment: I have imported a & b and made a presentation. However, they wanted the code not being exposed and for that they wanted to use deployment. How can I overcome this or what can i use to deploy the models?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by deployment and not exposing code. Do you mean like an `exe` file? If so, your question should be how to turn your script to an executable, or better yet, google existing solutions